# Matrix heatmap in ggplot not consistent in upper and lower triangles

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, igraph, sna

For some reason, this symmetrized matrix is plotting with either no data in the lower triangle of the heatmap or just a little as shown in the below figure. I can't figure out why it's happening. Any guesses? I've shared the first 100 rows of the dataset in the example below.

[image: Heatmap]

I'm using the following:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
Edgelist = "from  to    weight
2D16  31C1       3
2D16  3215       4
2D16  3AFD       3
2D16  3CFF       3
2D16  4777       2
2D16  48E2       3
2D16  4BAA       3
2D16  4FBB       3
2D16  5323       1
2D16  5A68       4
2D16  5D78       4
2D16  5D9E       4
2D16  5E0F       1
2D16  6BF3       2
2D16  6DBC       2
2D16  6EFC       2
2D16  6FB0       4
2D16  714B       3
2D16  735B       1
2D16  7E8A       3
2D16  7F77       1
2D16  8761       4
2D16  82D8       3
2D16  8BE7       2
2D16  8D8C       4
2D16  90B1       1
2D16  9116       1
2D16  9264       3
2D16  99CB       3
2D16  9A69       3
2D16  A26F       3
2D16  A975       3
2D16  AC37       2
2D16  B190       3
2D16  B261       2
2D16  B6DE       3
2D16  B7FD       1
2D16  BAB5       4
2D16  BDB5       1
2D16  C044       2
2D16  C1D9       4
2D16  C400       2
2D16  C574       2
3011  3011       3
3011  31C1       3
3011  3215       3
3011  3AFD       3
3011  3CFF       3
3011  4777       2
3011  48E2       3
3011  4BAA       3
3011  4FBB       3
3011  5323       3
3011  55E2       1
3011  5594       2
3011  5A68       3
3011  5D78       3
3011  5D9E       2
3011  6155       1
3011  6BF3       3
3011  6EFC       1
3011  6FB0       3
3011  714B       2
3011  7E8A       3
3011  843C       1
3011  8761       3
3011  82D8       3
3011  8BE7       1
3011  8D8C       3
3011  90B1       2
3011  9116       1
3011  9264       1
3011  99CB       2
3011  9A69       3
3011  A26F       3
3011  A975       3
3011  AC37       3
3011  B190       1
3011  B261       3
3011  B7FD       2
3011  BAB5       3
3011  BDB5       1
3011  C1D9       1
3011  C574       3
31C1  2D16       3
31C1  3011       3
31C1  31C1      15
31C1  3215      15
31C1  3AFD      15
31C1  3CFF      13
31C1  4777      10
31C1  48E2      15
31C1  4BAA      15
31C1  4FBB      14
31C1  5323       9
31C1  55E2       1
31C1  5594       4
31C1  5A68      13
31C1  5D78      12
31C1  5D9E      13"
Data <- read.table(text=Edgelist, header = TRUE)
graph <- graph.data.frame(Data, directed = FALSE)

V(graph)$comm <- membership(optimal.community(graph))
node_list <- get.data.frame(graph, what = "vertices")
edge_list <- get.data.frame(graph, what = "edges") %>%
  inner_join(node_list %>% select(name, comm), by = c("from" = "name")) %>%
  inner_join(node_list %>% select(name, comm), by = c("to" = "name")) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(comm.x == comm.y, comm.x, NA) %>% factor())
all_nodes <- sort(node_list$name)

plot_data <- edge_list %>% mutate(
  to = factor(to, levels = all_nodes),
  from = factor(from, levels = all_nodes))

  ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = from, y = to, fill = weight)) +
       geom_tile() +
       theme_bw() +
       scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
       scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
       theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0),
            aspect.ratio = 1,
            legend.position = "bottom") +  
              scale_color_viridis(discrete = FALSE, option = "D") +
              scale_fill_viridis(discrete = FALSE)
```

Comment: it will be easier to try to help you if you provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. If the data is too large, you can recreate the problem using some dummy data, or using just a part of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I've updated my original post with some sample data